Why does the test function have to vanish on the boundary in the weak formulation of the poisson equation?
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a lipschitz domain with boundary $\partial \Omega$ and consider the poisson equation $-\Delta u = f$ on $\Omega$ with boundary condition $u= u_D$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $u_D$ is given. By multiplying the poisson equation with a test function which vanishes on $\partial \Omega$, we can formally derive the weak formulation of the poisson equation, namely
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx = \int_{\Omega} fv\,dx\quad \forall v\in H^1_0(\Omega).$$
The imposed condition for $v$ on the boundary is essential, since it allows us to conclude that the boundary term in greens formula vanishes.
In the book "Solving PDEs in Python" by H. Langtangen and A. Logg, chapter 2.1.1 p. 13, the authors indicate that there are deeper reasons why one has to require this property and refer to "Introduction to Numerical Methods for Variational Problems" by H. Langtangen and K.-A. Mardal. On page 4, they are adressing this topic and refer to a later part of the book (which i wasn't able to find).
Could someone explain to me what the authors might mean by their comments?

Related discussion: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/how-to-properly-apply-non-homogeneous-dirichlet-boundary-conditions-with-fem

One deeper reason is so that the equation can be interpreted in a distributional sense (which allows a "weak formulation" even when the integrals don't make sense). When $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, the weak formulation is the distributional definition of $-\Delta u = f$. More detail below:
Regard $u$ as an element of $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, the space of distributions on $\Omega$. Then $\Delta : \mathcal{D}'(\Omega) \to \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ satisfies
$$(-\Delta u, \phi) = (\nabla u, \nabla \phi) = (u, -\Delta \phi), \hspace{12pt}\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega).$$
Thus to say $-\Delta u = f$ is exactly to say that $(f, \phi) = (\nabla u, \nabla \phi)$ for all $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Now for the pairings to be defined as integrals, we need, for instance, $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. Then $-\Delta u = f$ reads as $\int_{\Omega} f\overline{\phi}\,dx = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \overline{\nabla \phi}\,dx$ for all $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. This identity extends to all $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ since $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$
